# shortest way to create 2d array certain size

Tags: javascript

What is the shortest way to create a 2d array of a certain size?

I figured that following code is pretty short, but can you do it with even less code?

```
var x = 5;
var y = 7;
var my2dArray = (new Array(y)).fill(0).map(
                                            function(){
                                               return new Array(x);
                                            }
                                          );
```

Comment: What's the point of the question? Code golf questions are off topic here.

Comment: It is not about code golf, I am just getting tired of having to use multiple lines for `for` loops when creating new 2d arrays.

Comment: I don't think you need `.fill(0)`.

Comment: Write a function for it, use the function in the rest of your code. I don't see where the problem is. Besides, there are no multidimensional arrays in JavaScript. There are arrays of arrays, which is not the same data structure. Plus, JS arrays expand as needed, you don't need to pre-fill them at all.

Comment: @Barmar you do need it, since the map callback will not be called on 'empty' array entries.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Array.apply(0, Array(x)).map(function() { return Array.apply(0, Array(y)); })
```

Simpler if you write a little convenience routine

```
function make_array(x) { return Array.apply(0, Array(x)); }
```

then

```
make_array(x).map(function() { return make_array(y);} )
```

or if you prefer

```
make_array(x).map(make_array.bind(0, y))
```

If you're writing ES6:

```
Array(...Array(x)).map(() => Array(y));
```

If you'd prefer to use `fill`, since you seem to have it available:

```
Array(x).fill().map(function() { return Array(y); });
```

or somewhat more concisely in ES6, using an arrow function:

```
Array(x).fill().map(() => Array(y));
```

It turns out `Array#fill` requires no argument; without it, it replaces absent elements with undefineds.

Comment: Not to forget ES6 array comprehensions `[for (i in Array(y).fill(x)) Array(i)]`.

Comment: Would `Array(x).fill(Array(y))` also work? No it won't as that will fill the array with references to the object `Array(y)` >.<

Answer (score 3):

What about building your own Class ?

```
function Array2D(xSize, ySize, initialValue) {
  initialValue=initialValue || 0;
  // create an flat empty array filled with the initial value 
  var length = xSize*ySize;
  var innerArray = new Array(length);
  for (var i=0; i<length; i++) innerArray[i] = initialValue;
  // accessors
  this.getAt = function(x, y) { return innerArray[x+xSize*y]};
  this.setAt = function(x, y, val) { innerArray[x+xSize*y]=val};
}
```

Use with :

```
var myArray2d = new Array2D(5,7);

myArray2d.setAt(1,1,3);
var value = myArray2d.getAt(1,1);        // == 3
var anotherValue = myArray2d.getAt(2,2); // == 0
```

Comment: Nice one, an actual 2D array implementation. +1

Comment: Agreed--Nice answer  +1, casting awkward fixed-sized multi-dimensional arrays into a single, flattened one-dimensional array may not be the shortest code, but it "feels right" and offers operational efficiencies at the small cost of 1 multiply and 1 addition.